# Why am I getting the error: Cannot convert value of type '[UIImage?]' to expected argument type '[UIImage]'?

Tags: swift, uiimage, option-type

I have declared a public variable: `var ImagesOnClick: [UIImage?] = []`
Then I save the users images to the array with

```
Image.resolve(images: images, completion: {  resolvedImages in
        ImagesOnClick = resolvedImages
        topVC.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```

However when I go to display the images by doing this: `setupImageViewer(images: ImagesOnClick)` I get the following error:

`Cannot convert value of type '[UIImage?]' to expected argument type '[UIImage]'`

If I go an change the variable `ImagesOnClick` from `[UIImage?]` to `[UIImage]` I get the error:

`Cannot assign value of type '[UIImage?]' to type '[UIImage]'` in the `ImagesOnClick = resolvedImages` line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you declare it `[UIImage?]` instead of `[UIImage]`?  Do you really need placeholder objects in your array that aren't actually images?

Comment: If you look at the end of my question I say what happens if I declare it how you said to do it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that part.  So, instead of a simple assignment, you might need `for img in resolvedImages {
    if let img = img {
        ImagesOnClick.append(img)
    }
}`.